# select row from one table where value exists from array from another table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two tables.

1. **`Users table`** have columns

   - `member_group` equals to

     - Admin
     - Marketing
     - Sales
   - `zone` equals to

     - North
     - West
     - East
2. **`Meetings table`** have columns

   - `for_member_group`
   - `for_zone` columns.

`for_member_group` and `for_zone` may contain multiple values with comma separation.

**E.g.**

- `for_member_group` = Admin,Sales
- `for_member_group` = Admin,Marketing,Sales

  And same with `for_zone` column too.

Now I want to send emails to that particular meeting.

**E.g.** From Meetings table row 3 with values like `for_member_group` = 'Admin,Marketing' and `for_zone`='East,West'

Now mail should be sent to Admin and Marketing name containing rows and East and West containing zone names only form **`Users Table`**

**BUT USER QUERY is not working....** No user selected and no email gets sent...

I also tried `echo $userdata['email'];` But nothing echoed...and  No Error is seen...

I have tried as follows :

```
<?php
    $qry = "select * from $meetings where meeting_start > $today order by meeting_start desc limit 1";
    $results = $database->get_results($qry);
    foreach($results as $lecture_data){
        $for_member_group = $lecture_data['for_member_group'];
        $for_zone = $lecture_data['for_zone'];
        $userquery = "select * from $users where member_group IN('$for_member_group') and zone IN('$for_zone') ";
        $userresult = $database->get_results($userquery);
        foreach ($userresult as $userdata){
            echo $userdata['email'];
            ob_start();
   ?>

   <!-- EMail HTML and PHP Coding-->


 <?php

  rest php code
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: @ErwannBestard No email is getting sent...

Comment: use query like this IN(".$for_member_group.")

Comment: You should try to echo the answer to debug the program because your bug may be in the mail script

Comment: There is no code to send a mail

Comment: @NicoHaase That is not given here... But it is there... I tried without where clause in Userquery and emails are getting triggered to all users...Problem is with IN clause in query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$for_member_group` seems to be a CSV string. You have to quote all elements to use in `IN()` statement. Note that you should test if `$for_member_group` and `$for_zone` are not empty before to use them.

```
$mem_quote = "'".implode("','", explode(',', $for_member_group))."'";
$zon_quote = "'".implode("','", explode(',', $for_zone))."'";
// $mem_quote will be equals to 'Admin','Marketing'
$userquery = "select * from $users 
              where member_group in($mem_quote) 
                and zone in($zon_quote)";
```

The query will look like:

```
select * from $users 
 where member_group in('Admin','Marketing') 
   and zone in('East','West')
```

Comment: thnx and tried...but giving syntax error, unexpected '$for_member_group' (T_VARIABLE) in

Comment: @DrMJ Sorry, I've missing a comma. Please look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error please try this query.

```
$userquery = "select * from $users where member_group IN(".$for_member_group.") and zone IN (".$for_zone.") ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `FIND_IN_SET()`

Just like below:

```
$userquery = "select * from $users where (FIND_IN_SET('Admin',member_group) OR FIND_IN_SET('Sales',member_group) ) and (FIND_IN_SET('North',zone) OR FIND_IN_SET('West',zone))";
```

Comment: Please add more condition with OR condition if we have more values of member_group

Comment: It is not possible because meeting table may contain various rows with various values for column for_member_row and user member_group names may increase in coming days... So IN is perfect for me...But unfortunately, It is not working...